# PHP / MySQL How to get values from one table and check against another table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm creating a small voting application. I need to get the images and their vote counts from one table, and then check another vote table to see if the user has already voted for each of these images already.

To get the images from the image table I'm doing this:

```
  SELECT id, file_name, total_votes 
    FROM _images 
   WHERE approved = 1 
ORDER BY total_votes DESC 
   LIMIT ".($page*5).", 5"
```

But I also need to check in the "vote" table that their userid isn't already associated with the (image) id from this query. I only need to show 5 images at a time, hence the LIMIT applied to the first query.

I'm not sure whether I need to do some joining or multiple queries.

my vote table has fields:

- id
- voter_id
- image_id

EDIT:
Thanks for all your feedback.
Some more info:

total_votes felt dirty when I put it in there, but I couldn't work out a better way to count up the votes each time. Wouldn't it be inefficient if every time there was a vote cast, or a request to view the leaderboard that all the votes had to be tallied and sorted?
Forgive me for my sins - I'm not a database programmer!

Comment: Question: Is Total_Votes a column?  Somehow I doubt that

Comment: well total_votes was a hack I put in there until I worked out a better way to calculate the votes each time. Won't it be quicker to do that than add them all up each time from the vote table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using LEFT JOIN/IS NULL:

```
   SELECT i.id, i.file_name, i.total_votes 
     FROM _images i
LEFT JOIN VOTES v ON v.image_id = i.id
                 AND v.voter_id = ?
    WHERE approved = 1 
 ORDER BY total_votes DESC 
    LIMIT ".($page*5).", 5"
```

#### Using `NOT EXISTS`

```
   SELECT i.id, i.file_name, i.total_votes 
     FROM _images i
    WHERE approved = 1 
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                       FROM VOTES v
                      WHERE v.image_id = i.id
                        AND v.voter_id = ?)
 ORDER BY total_votes DESC 
    LIMIT ".($page*5).", 5
```

#### Using `NOT IN`

```
  SELECT i.id, i.file_name, i.total_votes 
    FROM _images i
   WHERE approved = 1 
     AND i.id NOT IN (SELECT v.image_id
                      FROM VOTES v
                     WHERE v.voter_id = ?)
ORDER BY total_votes DESC 
   LIMIT ".($page*5).", 5
```

#### Suggested Reading:

- http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/
- http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/

Comment: Ok I deleted my answer because as you pointed out I misread the question.  I don't get why OP would have a column for total_votes rather than just counting votes..

Comment: @babonk: I prefer to use a view to hide the COUNT(*) I'd use to get the value, but it can be a performance issue to calculate that vs storing the value.

Comment: Thanks for these OMG Ponies. I'm not sure if my question was clear enough. I actually want all results back as well as a Boolean that shows if there is already a vote match.